# Как исправить WebDriverException при ожидании более 1м(примерно), когда запуска автотеста происходит на удалёнке?

Tags: linux, selenium, docker

Есть сервер, на котором запускаем автотесты на удаленке.
Используем selenoid + docker + UI selenoid VNC.
Автотесты запускаем через IntelliJ IDEA через gradle в 4 потока.

Когда запускаю автотест, где в сценарии прописано выполнить ожидание ~60+ секунд, то происходит следующее:
1) Через ~60 секунд после запуска происходит как-будто разрыв соединения.
Лог UI VNC:
[image]
2) Еще через ~3 минуты в IntelliJ IDEA приезжает исключения WebDriverException.

```
com.codeborne.selenide.ex.ElementNotFound
        Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
```

При этом в следующих сценариях этой фичи и следующей происходят также падения с WebDriverException, он даже не может подняться. Дальше фичи отрабатывают штатно.

Я думал, что дело в таймаутах контейнера selenoid и выставил ему 10м всем трём параметрам:

```
   "-service-startup-timeout",
    "10m",
    "-session-attempt-timeout",
    "10m",
    "-session-delete-timeout",
    "10m"
```

Но это никак не помогло.

Может будут идеи, где искать проблему? Вероятно, где-то еще присутствует явный таймаут, который всё ломает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решение таково: необходимо в файле конфига docker-compose.yml выставить:

```
--args "-timeout 10m "
```

Оно и решает проблему.